# Printing image flie from browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox

I am trying to print an image from a browser.

For example: http://www.canadianpetconnection.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Cats1.jpg

I want my printed page to not have any margins on any side such that the image starts from top left of the page.

I also want that the width of the printed image should be fixed, say 8inches.

Is there any CSS/JS/HTML workaround?

Edit: I would be fine If I need to change a few settings in the printout popup that comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media print` in CSS and set the image width and height to the desired dimension. The rest of the settings you can manage in the browser printing section.

```
@media print {
    img {width: ?px; height: ?px; }
}
```

You can use even relative units for image properties.

As regarding your request to expand the image width to the device screen resolution, and then print the resulting image, i think it's almost impossible, because these settings you are managing from the printer device drivers.

Answer (score 0):

`CSS MEdia Types` will help you. See below link. (use @media print)

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media screen
  {
  p.test {font-family:verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
  }
@media print
  {
  p.test {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px;width:300px;}
  }
@media screen,print
  {
  p.test {font-weight:bold;}
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason for adding the font to the jpg?